# Self-powered bluetooth receiver with 3.5mm TRS (often: "universal stereo adapter")

Tags: bluetooth, audio-adapters

I'm seeking recommendations for a self-powered (rechargeable) Bluetooth receiver with an integrated 3.5mm male TRS plug.  It's a stand-alone device which enables use of Bluetooth headphones/speakers with a device that supports a standard 3.5mm mini stereo jack.

Ideally it should:

- use a micro USB connector for charging
- offer some indication of battery level (visual or audible)
- decent range

If you have experience with multiple devices your comparison is much appreciated.

The device shown below is the Plantronics 35BAA which was sold with the Plantronics Pulsar 590A, but is no longer manufactured.  It relied on a proprietary charging connector (not micro USB), but was otherwise a very satisfactory device.  Bonus points: *Did Plantronics release a successor to this?*

[image: Plantronics 35BAA]

Answer (score 1):

I actually just bought this:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01B4W40VC/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01B4W40VC)

This has Rx/Tx so its a receiver and transmitter.

What sets this one apart from all the rest is: you can use it while its charging.

There are cheaper ones that you cant use while its charging so you have to wait.

Also has excellent reviews.

Has micro USB as charging port.
Has LED to indicate on/off Other light colors/modes to indicate charging/paired/pairing/etc (about 8 hours continuous use)
Latest Bluetooth 4.1 so range should be 33ft with no barriers (your milage may wary).

Specifications: 
- Bluetooth Compliance: Bluetooth V4.1, CSR 8670 chipet, A2DP
- Transmit Range: up to 33ft / 10m 
- Supports: Dual Stream (TX mode); Multi-Point (RX mode)
- Codec: APT-X LL(TX), APT-X(TX), SBC(TX), SBC(RX)
- Working Time: about 8 hours
- Charging Time: 2 hours / 5V; can be used while being recharged
- Dimension: L 4.6 x W 3.3 x H 0.97 cm / 1.81 x 1.30 x 0.38 in 
- Net Weight: 0.51 oz / 14.5 g

IMPORTANT:
- Please plug in the power adapter before turning on TROND BT-DUO when using external power source;
- TROND BT-DUO will only use aptX Low Latency when your BT headset, speaker or receiver does support aptX LL. Otherwise, TROND BT-DUO will pair down to aptX or SBC;
- The latency of 40ms is still unacceptable for live sound monitoring. Therefore, musicians beware! TROND BT-DUO may not suit your needs.